# If the speed of light were frame-dependent, how would physical laws be different in a moving object?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames

One common answer to why the speed of light is frame-independent is that is the only principle consistent the Maxwell's laws being valid in all reference frames. If the speed of light were frame-dependent (like the speed of a baseball), how would the laws of electrostatics (Maxwell's equations) change in moving object or create a *priveliged* frame of reference? I am looking for a basic answer that can be reduced to an familiar everyday phenomenon like a mirror, cell phone, or something that could be explained to schoolchild without invoking the mathematical machinery of Maxwell's Equations. My hope that this explanation will reduce the originally counter-intuitive frame-independent speed of light to something more intuitive that people are familiar with.

One answer I saw here was about whether you would see your reflection in a mirror that was travelling at the speed of light and claimed that the light would travel back at zero speed (2c - 2c = 0). This is not satisfying because the mirror could easily be replaced with a reflective wall and the light beam with a racket-ball that was hit a at a constant speed equal to the speed of the train (v). The speed of the racket-ball would then be 2v relative to the ground outside, would hit the reflective wall and bounce back at speed 2v (assuming perfect reflectivity). The racket-ball would then reach the person at a speed of v relative to the train since the reflective wall was travelling at a speed of v as well. I like this starting point, but I would like an answer that is more satisfying where light could not be replaced readily with a ball or other massive object.

Comment: There's not a unique answer to this question. You would have to modify Maxwell's equations in *some* way for the speed of light to be frame dependent. But there are multiple ways you *could* modify Maxwell's equations, and exactly how you would see a difference with "standard" physics would depend on exactly what modification you were interested in. Maybe one relatively model-independent test would be the Michelson-Morley experiment.

Comment: If there's an absolute rest frame, then there is no reason not to replace light with a massive object.

Answer (score 1):

If Maxwell's laws were frame-dependent, then the power output of an electric generating station would vary on a 24-hour basis with the earth's rotation, a one-year basis with the earth's orbit around the sun, and a 250 million-year-basis as the solar system orbits the center of our galaxy.

By mapping out that variation it would be possible for us to locate the geometric center of the universe, using a device that measures the speed of light in the direction we choose as we travel at different velocities. That would then be the origin of the big bang and it would be from that direction that the cosmic microwave background emanated. Looking away from that center into deep space, we would be looking in the direction of things that haven't happened yet.

If electromagnetism were Galilean invariant, then the speed of light would be the sum of the velocity of light plus the velocity of its source. In such a universe, it would be common to observe effects before their causes, if the cause were moving towards us. Consider the following case: you are in the middle of a road and in the distance a fire truck with its lights on is speeding towards you. Between you and the truck is a side road with a slow-moving car on it which is on a collision course with the fire truck at the intersection. Because of Galilean relativity, the light from the speeding truck reaches you before the light from the slow-moving car, and you see the truck swerve to miss the car- *before the car reaches the intersection*.

In the famous coil-and-moving magnet experiment, we could tell whether it was the magnet that was actually moving or if it was the coil instead by watching the ammeter connected to the coil. In this way we could measure absolute velocities relative to the preferred rest frame attached to the center of the universe.

Comment: If "the speed of light" were frame-dependent, we wouldn't have a finite speed of causality, so I don't see why we'd observe effects before causes.

Comment: @J.G. have a good example of how that would work but need to go to bed now. If I have time tomorrow I'll write it up and edit my answer.